Non Vanishing Stepsize Q-learning
The first papers on q-learning uses stepsizes $(\alpha_n)_n\subset (0,1)$ such that
$$
\sum_n \alpha_n = \infty
$$
but
$$
\sum_n \alpha^2_n < \infty.
$$
Recently while skimming through Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis' book on Neurodynamic programming on Proposition $4.4$ I saw the following statement:
Let $r_t$ be given by
$$
r_{t+1}(i) = (1-\alpha_t(i)) r_t(i) + \alpha_t(i) ( (Hr_t)(i)+w_t(i),
$$
where $w_t$ is stochastic and satisfies $E[w_t(i)|\mathcal F_t]=0$ for all $i$ and  $t$ and
$$
E[w^2_t(i)|\mathcal F_t \ \leq A + B \| r_t\|^2
$$
for any norm on $\mathbb R^n$. Here we assume that $H$ is a pseudo contraction, i.e., $\| Hr - r^* \| \leq \beta \| r- r^* \|$ for all $r \in \mathbb R^n$ for some $r^*$, where $\beta <1$. Then $r_t$ converges to $r^*$ with probability $1$ when $ \sum_n \alpha_n = \infty$ and $\sum_n \alpha^2_n = \infty$
Here essentially $H$ acts as the value iteration algorithm. There is no proof given for it so I was not able to understand at which stage they even use $\sum_n \alpha^2_n = \infty$, but after the statement it is mentioned that it will be used in Chapter $5$. In Chapter $5$, it is only used in Proposition $5.5$, where it is also assumed $\sum_n \alpha^2_n <\infty$. I am not sure if this is the right place to ask for this but, is this an actual typo that they assumed $\sum_n \alpha^2_n = \infty$ in the statement? Are there any known convergence conditions for $Q$-learning under such condition? I only have the physical copy of the book so cannot post screenshot of the actual statement sorry about that.
